# Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP only for the home page domain

Tags: http, .htaccess, firefox, https

Since I have updated Firefox to 14.0.1 it puts automatically https in the domain of our online shop.

I need a code for the .htaccess file so that only the startpage i.e. www.example.com gets redirected/forced into www.example.com when Firefox 14.0.1 changes it into https://www.example.com

so only https://www.example.com should become www.example.com

Does someone knows the code for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note, if you redirect from https to http you'll trigger a warning in client some browsers.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Why would you want to redirect users to a *less* secure version of your site?

Comment: My site uses SSL only in the cart and checkout folders. The problem is that the new firefox puts https when I just type www.example.com, so many users having the new firefox visiting our shop are getting https immediatly.

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will rewrite all to insecure.

If you only want a specific page to match, make the rewrite rule less inclusive like below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This will also work:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(|/)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It should only be for the startpage www.example.com, not for all the other folders. What code do I need for that?

Comment: @user1424612 no problem... If it worked for you please mark my answer as the correct one and maybe upvote it:)